# Updated from EE 2.5.2 to 2.7.3 channel:form outputs error tags

Tags: channel-form

I updated EE 2.5.2 to 2.7.3, changed the exp:safecracker tag to exp:channel:form.

Sending a new entry with no content outputs not an error message as expected it shows the tags like

```
{field_errors}
   {error}
{/field_errors}
```

channel:form has this parameter: error_handling="inline"

I am wondering why that is and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#error-my-field-name), you need to use a different syntax for `error_handling="inline"`

```
{error:your_channel_field_name}
```

or if you don't want it inline

```
{if error}
  {error}
{/if}
```